# Flash10-ActionScript3:Can not connect to socket server

Tags: flash, sockets, actionscript

I wrote the C# codes have been running on local server side.

```
System.Net.Sockets.Socket server = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
server.Bind(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 4502));
server.Listen(int.MaxValue);
while (true)
{
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket client = server.Accept();
    if (client.Connected)
        client.Send(new byte[1]);
}
```

then built a swf file embedded in a html file on local web page——127.0.0.1/Socket.htm

```
public class WebSocket extends flash.display.Sprite
{
    private var Socket:flash.net.Socket = new flash.net.Socket();

    public function WebSocket()
    {
        flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*");
        flash.system.Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        flash.system.Security.loadPolicyFile("PolicyFile.xml");
        this.Socket.addEventListener( flash.events.Event.CONNECT, Socket_Connect );
        this.Socket.connect("127.0.0.1",4502);
    }

    private function Socket_Connect(event:Event):void
    {
        this.MyLabel.text= "The socket is now connected..." ; 
    }
}
```

here is the content of the "127.0.0.1/PolicyFile.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

the codes run without any error, but the CONNECT event is never fired.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket connections from Flash require a policy file served by the very same host. The Flash Player automatically tries to establish a socket connection to port 843 on the target machine to fetch a policy file. It's not sufficient to load a policy file with an ordinary request.

You can specify a different port like this:

```js
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:1843");
```

As you seem to work with .NET, this is a policy server for your platform: http://policyserver.codeplex.com.
You can also implement a policy server yourself. Just listen for connections and the input string `<policy-file-request/>\0`. After that, output the XML and close the socket. The Flash Player will then proceed with establishing the connection.

Example policy XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="4502" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Please also make sure that you listen for all relevant events on your socket (namely `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR`, `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR`, `Event.CLOSE`, `ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA`).